Unable to enforce schema on data read from jsonl file in Azure Databricks using pyspark
I'm tring to build a ETL pipeline in which I'm reading the jsonl files from the azure blob storage, then trying to transform and load it to delta tables in databricks.
I have created the below schema for loading my data :
schema = StructType([
    StructField("restaurantId", IntegerType(), nullable=False),
    StructField("reviewId", IntegerType(), nullable=False),
    StructField("text", StringType(), nullable=False),
    StructField("rating", DoubleType(), nullable=False),
    StructField("publishedAt", TimestampType(), nullable=False),
    StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType(), nullable=True)
])

I'm reading the jsonl files from the below code :
df = spark.read \
    .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") \
    .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .json(raw_file_location).cache()

But I get no results from the below code :
display(df.select(col("_corrupt_record")).where(col("_corrupt_record").isNotNull()))


There are many column which are null in my raw data and these are inserted to the table as null and the _corrupt_record column is null for that case. Please let me  know how to resolve this issue
My expectation is to see the corrupt record (the record which does not math the defined schema) populated for the failed records , for this I have also tried SQL queries to manully create the schema and load  the data but still doesn't works
Some good data :
[
    {
        "restaurantId": 101,
        "reviewId": 1001,
        "text": "Amazing food and excellent service. Highly recommend!",
        "rating": 4.5,
        "publishedAt": "2023-05-01T12:34:56Z"
    },
    {
        "restaurantId": 102,
        "reviewId": 1002,
        "text": "The ambiance was great but the food was just average.",
        "rating": 3.0,
        "publishedAt": "2023-05-02T15:20:10Z"
    }
]

Some Bad data that should go to _corrupt_record:
[
    {
        "restaurantId": null,  // Null value in a non-nullable field
        "reviewId": 1004,// Missing text column
        "rating": 4.0,
        "publishedAt": "2023-05-04T20:10:05Z"
    },
    {
        "restaurantId": 104,
        "reviewId": "1005",  // Incorrect data type for reviewId (should be Integer)
        "text": "Loved the dessert menu.",
        "rating": 4.7,
        "publishedAt": "2023-05-05T21:22:15Z"
    }
]


cache() is lazily evaluated. You need an action to bring the cache into play. Without the cache() you cannot filter on only the _corrupt_record column.

i did df.count() are reading but didn't make any difference. Also the column _corrupt_record is completely null after loading the data

Can you post some sample data where you'd expect records to go to _corrupt_record column?

@xuxu just updated the examples

Works just fine for me. nullability in the Pyspark Schema is not enforced, hence the third row won't be added to the _corrupt_record column. The fourth one does go to the column as expected.

what do you mean nullability in the pyspark schema is not enforce ? I don't want to accept the jsons that has missing field or null fields , how do I handle this case ?

nullable=False in the Pyspark Schema is meant for Spark SQL to optimize for the column. This is not enforced. You'll have to filter out these rows from the dataframe after you've read the data.

so what you mean is it will work for mismatch data type but not missing or null fields ?

Yes, that is correct.

According to this documentation, the cases to handle bad records are as follows:

Incomplete or corrupt records
Mismatched data types
Bad field names
Corrupted files
Missing files

In your case, it is related to data, and the following issues are handled:

Mismatched data types
Bad field names

Therefore, if your data doesn't match the column names or there is a data type mismatch, it is considered a bad record.
I have tried using the columnNameOfCorruptRecord and badRecordsPath options and obtained the same bad records.
Example 1:

Example 2:

In both examples, the bad record is the 2nd row, where there is a data type mismatch for the field reviewId.
What you are asking about the 1st row, which is missing a column, is not handled in JSON format but is handled in CSV format only when using the badRecordsPath option.

